# Change Password - SAP HANA Studio

Tags: authentication, hana, change-password

When I try to login with SAP HANA Studio (Eclipse with HANA Plugins - all up-to-date)

I get the following Dialog:

[image: Change password Dialog - before clicking on OK]

When I fill in the old password, new password and click on OK then I get the message:

**User null is required to change his or her password**

[image]

**How to fix this?**

I recently changed the windows password and HANA Studio is supposed to work with single sign on.

**Also not working when trying to change the passsword via Security → Users → <own user>:**

[image: HANA GUI to User]

[image: Dialog Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

Since single sign on should work besides database logon I changed the configuration:

From database user login:

[image: Existing configuration]

To OS user login:

[image: New configuration]

**2.**

Try changing the password via SQL: `alter user <myUser> "<newPassword>"`